# Missing helper "devise_controller?" in ApplicationController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I wanted to set layout to my Devise sign-in page, so I added the following to my ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  if devise_controller?
    layout "single_column_with_banner"
  end
 end
```

However, I get the following error:
**undefined method `devise_controller?' for ApplicationController:Class**

I can see that the helper method is specified in devise.rb, but I just can't access it from application controller.  I'm using Rails 3.2 (in process of migration from 2.3).  Any clues where I should look at?  As a last resort I can override SessionsController but I don't really want to do that yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like layout can be specified without either device_controller? or overriding SessionsController.  In order to specify layouts, place the following in *application.rb*:

```
config.to_prepare do
  Devise::SessionsController.layout "single_column_with_banner"
end
```